# Unable a Drop-down From scrolling

Tags: menu, kivy, dropdown, kivymd, overscroll

I am trying to make a kivymd dropdown that does not allow its content to scroll

Tried several times with kivymd version 1.1.1 and 1.2.0 and kivy version 1.9.0 and 2.0.0

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''

MDBoxLayout:

  MDAnchorLayout:

    MDRaisedButton:

      text: "Saikat"

      on_press: app.open_drop(self)

  MDWidget:

    md_bg_color: "red"

'''

class Test(MDApp):

  def build(self):

      return Builder.load_string(KV)

  def open_drop(self, x):

    MDDropdownMenu(

      caller = x,

      width_mult = 3,

      items= [

        { "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",

         "text": "Saikat"

        } ]

   ).open()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  Test().runTest().run
```

Trying many change to do so. Likely, effect_cls = "ScrollEffect", but did not work